# Non-integer sequencing in for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

For the code below I need a non-integer sequencing in R. Since, when I run the following code I receive an error "Error in datalist[[j]] <- DF1 :
attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex"

```
datalist = list()
for (j in seq(0, 1, 0.125)){
  DF1 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(seq(5,60,5), function(i) setNames(data.frame(rlnorm(n=10000, log(i^2 / sqrt((i*j)^2 + i^2)), sqrt(log(1 + ((i*j)^2 / i^2))))), i)))
  DF1$CV <- j
  datalist[[j]] <- DF1
}
DF2 = do.call(rbind, datalist)
```

Comment: What do you expect `datalist[[j]]` to mean when `j == 0.125`? Even if you could make it work, using non-integers for indices doesn't seem robust because of potential floating point round-off errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output from `seq` is not integer.  It is better to loop over the sequence of the vector.

```
v1 <- seq(0, 1, 0.125)
datalist <- vector('list', length(v1))
for(j in seq_along(v1)) {
      DF1 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(seq(5,60,5), function(i) setNames(data.frame(rlnorm(n=10000, log(i^2 / sqrt((i*j)^2 + i^2)), sqrt(log(1 + ((i*j)^2 / i^2))))), i)))
 DF1$CV <- v1[j]
 datalist[[j]] <- DF1
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The part of code (DF1$CV <- j) returns me numbers from 1 to 9. How do I extract the real values from v1 ?

Comment: @sm_050 sorry forgot about it.  It is `v1[j]`